# Why can't I scrape the following table

Tags: r, rvest

I'm using the code below in order to scrape a webpage's list.The result that I get is only the table's header.How can I scrape the whole table?

```
library(rvest)
theurl <- "http://www.forbes.com/midas/list/"
file<-read_html(theurl)
tables<-html_nodes(file, "table")
table1 <- html_table(tables[2], fill = F)
table1
c<-as.data.frame(lapply(table1, stack))
summary(c$values)
head(c$values)
```

Comment: Scraping Forbes is a violation of their ToS. 5 folks recently (the week of this post) received a very real legal action from LinkedIn for scraping that site. Sites can take ToS very seriously when they want to. Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Thanks for comment @hrbrmstr. I use it as a case study for learning purpose.

Comment: Doubtful. And I also doubt their legal team will believe that as well. There are tons of other places to try scraping exercises.