# Web scraping in R using rvest to extract table data

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract the full table content from the following link
https://www.forbes.com/global2000/list/#tab:overall

I used the following code to extract the data,however the code just returns the table heading but not the contents.I think this is because of the nature of the website design ? In this case how do I extract the full table data,what am I missing ?

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.forbes.com/global2000/list/#tab:overall"
html <- read_html(url)
node <- html%>%html_nodes("table")
company_data <- html_table(node)
company_data
```

Comment: Scraping Forbes is a violation of their ToS https://stackoverflow.com/q/39033432/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get extract a table from an HTML Page as a data.frame using XML and Rcurl in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49959431/how-do-i-get-extract-a-table-from-an-html-page-as-a-data-frame-using-xml-and-rcu)